# Overload resolution and user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overload-resolution

Consider this example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int){cout << "Foo(int)\n";}
    Foo(double){cout << "Foo(double)\n";}

    operator int()const{cout << "operator int()\n"; return 0;}
    operator double()const{cout << "operator double()\n"; return 0.;}
};

void bar(Foo){cout << "bar(Foo)\n";}
void bar(float){cout << "bar(float)\n";}



int main()
{

    int i = 5;
    bar(i); // whey bar(float) and not bar(Foo)?
}
```

- I know I shouldn't overload the "converting-ctor" to take relate types (here arithmetic types) but just for understanding better function matching and user-defined-conversion.
- Why the call to bar is resolved to `bar(float)` and not `bar(Foo)` as long as `Foo` has an exact match for this argument (`int`)?
- Does it mean that standard conversion is preferred over user-defined conversion?

Comment: "*I know I shouldn't overload the "converting-ctor" to take relate types (here arithmetic types)*" - there is nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is because defining only one conversion of those related types allows standard conversion before converting to class type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No it shouldn't define more than one conversion to or from arithmetic type (relate types by conversion). consider this example: `struct A
{
 A(int=0){cout << "A(int=0)\n";}
 A(double){cout << "A(double)\n";}
 operator int()const{cout << "A::op int()\n"; return 0;}
 operator double()const{cout << "A::op double()\n"; return 0;}
};
void foo(long double)
{
 cout << "foo(long double\n)";
}
int main()
{
 A a;
 foo(a);
}` as you can see the call to foo is ambiguous so we should only define one conversion operator and let compiler apply the standard conversion if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that standard conversion is preferred over user-defined conversion?

Yes. Standard conversions are always preferred over user-defined ones. See [this](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week20.htm)

In deciding on the best match, the compiler works on a rating system for the way the types passed in the call and the competing parameter lists match up. In decreasing order of goodness of match:

- An exact match, e.g. argument is a double and parameter is a double
- A promotion
- **A standard type conversion**
- **A constructor or user-defined type conversion**